# Response ContentType is not changed

Tags: json, model-view-controller, httpresponse

I have class:

```
public class UploadResult
{
    public UploadResult()
    {

    }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside controller method i return this class as json:

```
[HttpPost]
public UploadResult UploadFile()
{
    var jsResult = new UploadResult() { success = false, msg = "Test" };

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    return jsResult;
}
```

Since IE doesn't understand json file type, i would like to set contentType to "text/html". It is also required in documentation of my js library that contentType must be "text/html".

But response header has contentType is "application/json". How can I change that? Why it doesn't work when I explicitly set it to "text/html"?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched many similar solutions, but neither work for me.
Then i have managed to create something that finally works ok and maybe will help someone:

I have changed from UploadResult to HttpResponseMessage and add configuration formatter:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile()
    {
       //some code here ....

       return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new ObjectContent<UploadResult>(jsResult, Configuration.Formatters[0], "text/html")
        };
    }
```

This works well in all versions of IE.